# How can I print a result message for sending form's data using Fetch and Aurelia

Tags: javascript, fetch, aurelia

I'm getting an error "Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot set property 'resultMessage' of undefined" when I try to use fetch in Aurelia to post form's data and print out a message on the same webpage if it succeeded (${resultMessage}).

this.resultMessage = "New book added"; <= this line is resulting in error

add.js:

```
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client'

export class AddBooks{

    bookData = {}

    constructor() {
        this.resultMessage = ""
    }

    activate() {
         let client = new HttpClient();
    }

    addBook() {
        let client = new HttpClient();

        client.fetch('{address}', {
            'method': "POST",
            'body': json(this.bookData)
        })
        .then(function(response) {
           return response.json();
        })
       .then(function(data) {
          if(data.id) {
             console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
             this.resultMessage = "New book added"; 
        }
     });
    }
}
```

add.html:

```
<template>

  <form id="bookaddform" method="post" submit.delegate="addBook()">
    <div>
      <label for="bookTitle">Book Title</label>
      <input id="bookTitle" type="text" name="bookTitle" value.bind="bookData.title">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="bookPrice">Book Price</label>
      <input id="bookPrice" type="number" name="bookPrice" value.bind="bookData.price">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="bookDescription">Book Description</label>
      <input id="bookDescription" type="text" name="bookDescription" value.bind="bookData.description">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add your book">
  </form>

  ${resultMessage}

</template>
```

response-json

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "errors": []
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` in the `function` context is the function, not the class. Instead, use arrow function notation like so:

```
.then(data => {
          if(data.id) {
             console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
             this.resultMessage = "New book added"; 
        })
```

Now `this` should be the class.